# Keyboard shortcut for changing style of selected text (NOT the whole cell)

Tags: front-end, formatting, keyboard

For many years I have been using Alt+Shift+(number) to quickly change the style of text in a text cell. For example when I write descriptive text and want some of that text to look like input form, e.g., "The code x = 1 is used to set the value of x". Here I want the 'x = 1' part to look like input form. In many previous versions of Mathematica you highlighted the text that you wanted to change then pressed Alt+Shift+9. The Alt+Shift+(number) keybinding has been removed from version 10 so that it just acts like Alt+(number) and so Alt+Shift+9 changes the whole cell to input form.

How can the previous behavior be restored?

The official reply from Wolfram was

> "There is no documented way to change this feature back. However, for
>   changing the keyboard shortcuts, one could modify the file
>   "KeyEventTranslations.tr" in the subfolder
>   'SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources' of the Mathematica installation
>   directory. Since this is not documented, we cannot provide support on
>   modifying this file".

I didn't find this very helpful. Could somebody please advise me what to do.

Comment: This would appear to be platform dependent. Command+9 still styles a selection within a text cell in V10 running on OS X.

Comment: If you want to change the hotkeys you need to edit "KeyEventTranslations.tr" or for Menu entries the "MenuSetup.tr" file. There are quite some resources on the web and these forums on how to do that. The location of those files is OS dependent, of course.

Comment: @Wizard Well I looked but can't find anything that seems to show how to change the style of selected text. If you know of a suitable online resource please tell us its URL.

Answer (score 3):

This change of behavior is not intentional, and will be fixed in the next release of Mathematica. It was, ironically, an unforeseen consequence of fixing another bug involving modifier keys.

I regret the incomplete information given to you by Technical Support.  They were answering the question of how to customize key bindings--a common request, but not one officially supported at this time.  While there have been a very small number of tweaks and changes to officially documented shortcut keys, they generally should not change from version to version.